# TextField value changes for all cards

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building gym diary and have "cards" for each moves which includes " sets  reps  kg". So the code generates as many cards "Squat" and "Front-squat" in the view. The problem here is that I use controllerSets in both cards. If I change the "squat" sets number to "2" then "front-squat" number also changes to "2" because it uses the same controllerSets TextEditingController. This is my problem and please consider that there can be even 10 moves and I don't think I want to create 10 x 3 controllers for each of them. My question is how should I build this feature? the full code can be found here:

```
return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(
      _programMovesGen(program)[index],
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
    ), // Move name
    Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Flexible(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
            child: new TextFormField(
                controller: controllerSets,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: [
                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(2),
                ]),
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "sets ",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
        ),
        new Flexible(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: new TextFormField(
                controller: controllerReps,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: [
                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(2),
                ]),
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "reps",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
        ),
        new Flexible(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: new TextFormField(
                controller: controllerKgs,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: [
                  LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(2),
                ]),
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "kg",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
        ),
        Container(
            height: 60,
            width: 60,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.pink,
                width: 3.5,
              ),
            ),
            child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  IconData(57669, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                  size: 38,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                onPressed: () => {
                      _saveMove(_programMovesGen(program)[index]),
                    })),

        ///TODO add to db and previous added move
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

}

https://pastebin.com/m6zVLUAD

[image]

Comment: "If I change the 'squat' sets number then 'front-squat' number also changes."... what does it change to?

Comment: Edited the post to be more readble

Comment: is this the list of widgets?

Comment: it is list of widgets

Answer (score 1):

Make `arrays` of your `TextEditingControllers` like this:

```
List<TextEditingController> controllerSets = new List<TextEditingController>();
List<TextEditingController> controllerReps = new List<TextEditingController>();
List<TextEditingController> controllerKgs = new List<TextEditingController>();

TextEditingController sets = new TextEditingController(text: '3');
TextEditingController reps = new TextEditingController(text: '6');
TextEditingController kgs = new TextEditingController(text: '60');
```

in your `initState` method, do this:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
}
```

Now pass that `list index` in the `_saveMove` function, so it will look like this:

```
_saveMove(String moveName, int index) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      debugPrint("BEFORE SAVEDMOVES " + savedMoves);

      savedMoves += (moveName != "")
          ? moveName +
              ": " +
              controllerSets[index].text +
              " sets " +
              controllerReps[index].text +
              " reps " +
              controllerKgs[index].text +
              " kg\n"
          : "";
      prefs.setString('history', savedMoves);
    });
  }
```

Your `_buildCardContent()` function will be changed, as you have to pass `index` in the `controllers list` as well:

```
Widget _buildCardContent(int index) {
    controllerSets.add(sets);
    controllerReps.add(reps);
    controllerKgs.add(kgs);

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          _programMovesGen(program)[index],
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
        ), // Move name
        Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Flexible(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                child: new TextFormField(
                    controller: controllerSets[index],
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    inputFormatters: [
                      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(2),
                    ]),
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "sets ",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
            ),
            new Flexible(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: new TextFormField(
                    controller: controllerReps[index],
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    inputFormatters: [
                      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(2),
                    ]),
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "reps",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
            ),
            new Flexible(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: new TextFormField(
                    controller: controllerKgs[index],
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    inputFormatters: [
                      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(2),
                    ]),
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "kg",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
            ),
            Container(
                height: 60,
                width: 60,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.pink,
                    width: 3.5,
                  ),
                  /*gradient: RadialGradient(
                  radius: 0.50,
                  colors: [
                    Colors.blue,
                    Colors.yellowAccent,
                  ],
                ),*/
                ),
                child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      IconData(57669, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
                      size: 38,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => {
                          _saveMove(_programMovesGen(program)[index], index),
                        })),

            ///TODO add to db and previous added move
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hi, what am I suppose to put to controller: controllerSets, ? I have tried this: controller: controllerSets[index], but it does not work

Comment: I get error: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Comment: you have to assign as controllerSets[index] when you assigning it in TextField

Comment: This is the same situation as I have posted. I get error: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0. Does this mean that my initState does not run?

Comment: Filling in the error message:
I/flutter (30985): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (30985): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:145:60)
I/flutter (30985): #1      _ProgramScreenState._buildCardContent (package:gym_buddy/screens/programScreen.dart:205:47)

Comment: initState will run whenver page starts. Can you tell me the line number, on which error occurs? Its 205:47 of your programScreen.dart file.

Comment: Here is updated code as you wanted: https://pastebin.com/E5UPZ9FV and here is the error that it gives: https://pastebin.com/9szi13D3 I have tried to trace the error but I haven't found a solution for this.

Comment: Check the updated code, I have updated the code of initState() and added 3 lines in _buildCardContent() method and before initState() method.

Comment: Any progress on this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to separate the `gym card` to its own `class` and call it whenever you want 
something like this

```
class GymCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String excerciseName;

  GymCard({Key key, this.excerciseName}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _GymCardState createState() => _GymCardState();
}

class _GymCardState extends State<GymCard> {
  TextEditingController _setsController, _repsController, _weightController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _setsController = TextEditingController();
    _repsController = TextEditingController();
    _weightController = TextEditingController();
  }
  void _getExcerciseDetails (){
     _setsController.text;
    _repsController.text;
    _weightController.text;
    //do something with them
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        //Text for the name of exercise
        //Text(widget.excerciseName)
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: _setsController,
            ),
            //text for sets word
            TextField(
              controller: _repsController,
            ),
            //text for reps word
            TextField(
              controller: _weightController,
            ),
            //text for weight word
            //icon button
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }

 }
```

If you have something like program `class` you can add it as a `parameter` in the `widget` and 
pass it to the `controllers` in the `initstate` function:

```
//in initstate
_setsController.text = widget.program.sets;
//do this for the other two controllers
```

now return to program screen

```
return Scaffold(
  body: ListView(
       children: <Widget>[
              GymCard(program:programs[0],excerciseName : 'Squat'),
              GymCard(program:programs[1],excerciseName : 'bench press') //and so on
             ]
    )
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but you need to have different TextEditingController for every TextField out there. as this line suggests from the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes).

Connect the TextEditingController to a text field
Supply the TextEditingController to either a TextField or a TextFormField. **Once you wire these two classes together, you can begin listening for changes to the text field**.
and so you will be needing individual TextEditingController for every textfield out there on your screen and to get data from it.

ways to resolve this issue:

1. Create an array list from initState method and pass that textEditingController to your textField widget.
2. use blocPattern and streams more you can found on this -> [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29542)